# How to disable DEBUG logging from the "aws-java-sdk-NettyLoop-X-X" module?

Tags: asynchronous, logging, netty, log4j2, aws-java-sdk

I have a Java application, built with Gradle along side using a log4j2.xml file for logging purposes. In my java app, I have an asynchronous s3 client uploading a file to a bucket, however once the thread returns a response it LOGS the contents of the file which I do not want.

I have tried modifying the log4j2.xml file to set the logging level of the "aws-java-sdk" module to "OFF" but have had no success as building that app with the new configuration results in the same logging of the contents.

This is the current log4j2.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="JsonAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:EcsLayout.json"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="JsonLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="JsonAppender"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="JsonAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```